# changing image attribute after a set interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change a certain parameter in am image after every 3 second so that after every three seconds it will loop through 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. I am displaying all 0 on page load and then change the attribute through a set time out. The number is jumping from 0 to 9 and then not moving at all

Here is my js

```
var linkCons = "http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Numbers/";

setInterval(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++){
        $('.nine').attr('src',linkCons + "nw" + i + ".png")
    }
}, 3000);
```

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/AZe9b/2/

Comment: It works as you are writed it :) After 3 sec it changes the src from 1 to 9, but it is fast and you can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this it's me solution.

```
 var linkCons = "http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Numbers/";
 var i = 0;
 setInterval(function() {
    $('.nine').attr('src', linkCons + "nw" + ((i === 10) ? i = 0 : (i++)) +".png");    
 }, 3000);
```

Comment: @john-- this is exactly what I was looking for. Now I also see where I was making the error. Thanks for doing this

Answer (score 1):

It is actually looping through them all, just too quickly for you to see.  What you're doing is every three seconds it loops through all 10 options as quickly as possible.  It then stays on 9 for three seconds and repeats.  You should have a counter variable and do something like:

```
    var linkCons = "http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Numbers/";
    var count = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.nine').attr('src',linkCons+"nw"+count+".png");
        count++;
        if (count > 9)
        {
            count = 0;
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AZe9b/6/)

```
var linkCons = "http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Numbers/";
var i = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    $('.nine').attr('src', linkCons + "nw" + i+++".png");
    if(i === 10)  i = 0 ;
}, 3000);
```